# Writing financial data to database using Rblpapi and RMySQL

Tags: r, bloomberg, rmysql

I used Rblpapi to retrieve historic data, format is a list of data.frames. I now want to write that list of data into a MySQL database, I tried

`dbWriteTable(con,name="db_all",data,header=T)`, which gives me

> "unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for
>   signature ‘"MySQLConnection", "character", "list"’"

I have the feeling the problem is the list of data.frames, is there any easy way to insert this data from R into MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
df <- do.call("rbind", data)
dbWriteTable(con, name="db_all", df, header=T)
```